# How can I write an NSImage to a JPEG file in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsimage

A Swift question. Not an Obj-C question. *Please don't mark it as duplicate*

I am trying to write a class that generates a JPEG thumbnail on OS X. I *hope* I have something sensible that forms the scaled down NSImage but I'm struggling to write a JPEG file to disk.

```
class ImageThumbnail {
    let size = CGSize(width: 128, height: 128)
    var originalPath = ""

    init(originalPath: String){
        self.originalPath = originalPath
    }

    func generateThumbnail() {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: originalPath)

        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil) {
            let options: [NSString: NSObject] = [
                kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: max(size.width, size.height) / 2.0,
                kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true
            ]

            let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options)
            let scaledImage = cgImage.flatMap { NSImage(CGImage: $0, size: size) }

            // How do I write scaledImage to a JPEG file?
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage: `ImageThumbail(originalPath: "/path/to/original").generateThumbnail()`

Comment: I had seen "the duplicate" and the answers are in Obj-C (apart from the last answer which has no votes and doesn't work for me). Also it seems @JAL edited my text where I said I working in Swift.

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed the "Swift newbie" message because it was considered noise.  I have undeleted my answer, which differs slightly from the answer in the dupe post.  Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Do you want to take an image file and create a separate thumbnail (smaller) representation of it to store in a **separate** file, or do you want to add a thumbnail image to an existing image file by modifying and then saving that file? (The later is the way `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` is intended to be used, I believe).

Comment: I'd like to write the thumbnail to a separate file. Perhaps something like CGBitmapContextCreate and CGContextDrawImage would be more suitable?

Answer (score 7):

First you need to get a bitmap representation of the image, get a JPEG representation of that image (or whatever format you want), and then write the binary data to a file:

```
if let bits = scaledImage?.representations.first as? NSBitmapImageRep {
    let data = bits.representationUsingType(.NSJPEGFileType, properties: [:])
    data?.writeToFile("/path/myImage.jpg", atomically: false)
}
```

`NSBitmapImageFileType` gives you a choice of representations:

```
public enum NSBitmapImageFileType : UInt {

    case NSTIFFFileType
    case NSBMPFileType
    case NSGIFFileType
    case NSJPEGFileType
    case NSPNGFileType
    case NSJPEG2000FileType
}
```

Comment: Thanks for un-deleting this! My scaledImage doesn't seem to have any representations. The execution doesn't enter that branch. Do I have to create a representation first?

Comment: @henster I can't reproduce that issue.  I've initialized an `ImageThumbnail` object with a jpg image and see that it has at least one representation: `[<NSCGImageSnapshotRep:0x7fb570d54240 cgImage=<CGImage 0x7fb570c2e850>>]`.  What kind of image are you passing in to your class?

Comment: My issue in Swift 3 / Xcode 8 is that I see indeed a `NSCGImageSnapshotRep` but it doesn't cast as `NSBitmapImageRep`

Answer (score 2):

```
extension NSImage {
    func imagePNGRepresentation() -> NSData? {
        if let imageTiffData = self.tiffRepresentation, let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: imageTiffData) {
            // let imageProps = [NSImageCompressionFactor: 0.9] // Tiff/Jpeg
            // let imageProps = [NSImageInterlaced: NSNumber(value: true)] // PNG
            let imageProps: [String: Any] = [:]
            let imageData = imageRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageFileType.PNG, properties: imageProps) as NSData?
            return imageData
        }
        return nil
    }
}

if let thumbImageData = thumbimage.imagePNGRepresentation() {
    thumbImageData.write(toFile: "/path/to/thumb.png", atomically: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that either in Swift 3 `NSCGImageSnapshotRep` no longer casts as `NSBitmapImageRep`, or this works for only some images (I can't tell which is true as I only encountered images that do *not* cast to NSBitmapImageRep in my case when loading some JPEG data into an NSImage, then trying to encode a JPEG representation again).

This slight alteration to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35003291/504931) works for me in Swift 3 + macOS Sierra SDK in Xcode 8:

```
let cgImage = img.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!
let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImage)
let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageFileType.JPEG, properties: [:])!
```

(Please excuse the forced unwraps, just there for brevity – definitely optionals to check in production code given current SDK has introduced optionality here.)